# Wordpress - Adding script just above body tag for a custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, footer, custom-post-type

I've inherited a website that has custom post types.

I want to add my google re-marketing code to the footer of the site for individual pages just above the body tag.

In the admin where I edit the custom post type post, I can see this in the url...

edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=hotels&tag_ID=11&post_type=hhmm_apartments

Using this as a clue my method so far has been to add some code to my child theme's footer.

`<?php if ( is_tax ( hotels ) ) : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
hrental_id: MMHOTEL
};
</script><?php endif; ?>`

This works by making the script appear for all of these custom post types (hotels) but how do I also target the 'tag_ID=11', this seems to be the identifier of individual page.

I hope this makes sense

Thanks

tigs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the is_singular to add a script to a specific custom post type (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

The url you reference looks like you are editing the taxonomy (categories of the custom posts) and not the actual post itself, it looks like your Custom Post Type name is 'hhmm_apartments' and 'hotels' is a taxonomy of that post type. I would use the code below to add the script to all individual posts that are custom post types of 'hhmm_apartments'

```
<?php if(is_singular('hhmm_apartments')){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
hrental_id: MMHOTEL
};
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

If you want to target posts the specific term with the id 11 of the taxonomy of 'hotels' I would use has_term (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

See the code below for this one.

```
<?php if( has_term( '11', 'hotels' ) ) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
hrental_id: MMHOTEL
};
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope I'm understanding you correctly, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You understood perfectly. Your second code was what I required. You have made my day thanks Paul!!